# efficient way to parse through JSON object when object name is dynamic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

is this possible? if so how would i accomplish this?

x will be a json object retrieved via an ajax call to the server, and will contain different object names, depending on the name i need to go through and complete different actions.

I would like to know if i could access the object keys and use switch or another method to do an action based on the object name, the json object is dynamic hence why i thought switch would be best to cover each scenario.

JSON

```
x = {
"a": {
    "name": "john",
    "age": "53",
    "more": "foo"
},
"b": {
    "test": "testing",
    "x": "c",
    "z": "b"
},
"c": {
    "foo": "testing",
    "bar": "2",
    "more": "lol"
}
}
```

example switch using the above json

```
switch (x)
{
    case 'a':
        var name = a['name']; // should equal john, need the correct way of doing this
        break;

    case 'b':
        var x = b['x']; // would equal c
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just iterate

```
for (var key in x) {
    switch (key) {
        case 'a': 
            var name = x[key]['name'];
        break;
        case 'b':
            var _x = x[key]['x'];
        break;
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gWDTb/1/)

or just check for certain properties

```
for (var key in x) {
    if ('name' in x[key]) var name = x[key]['name'];
    if ('test' in x[key]) var test = x[key]['test'];
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gWDTb/2/)

Comment: @Bergi - Oh no, no no no, it's totally different, I'm passing in a string key while the OP is passing the object to switch, completely different even if the code looks exactly the same.

Comment: Oh, he really passed the object into the switch? I didn't get that and it was expecting that the `x` he was passing is a property name. But yeah, now that you say it, this reveals to be pseudo code only…

Answer (score 1):

Create another object and name methods the same way as keys in your `x` object:

```
var obj = {}
var x = {
"a": {
    "name": "john",
    "age": "53",
    "more": "foo"
},
"b": {
    "test": "testing",
    "x": "c",
    "z": "b"
},
"c": {
    "foo": "testing",
    "bar": "2",
    "more": "lol"
}
}

var methods = {
    "a": function(a) { obj.name = a.name },
    "b": function(b) { obj.y = b.x },
    "c": function(c) { ... }
}


for(var key in x) {
      if (methods.hasOwnProperty(key))
         methods[key](x[key])
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but you should add in a `if (key in methods)` test.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this - at least not in the manner you have outlined with a `switch`. I'd suggest using standard `if` conditions to test if the property exists in the `x` object, then retrieve the required information from it.

Something like this:

```
if (x["a"]) {
    var name = x["a"]["name"];
    // do something...
}
else if (x["b"]) {
    var y = x["b"]["x"];
    // do something...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a switch in a for-loop. The set of possible property names seems to be limited, well-defined and known to you, so you could just go through them:

```
var x = {…};

if ("a" in x) {
    var name = x.a.name;
    // do the "name" action
}
if ("b" in x)
    var _x = x.b.x;
    // do the "x" action
}
…
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (pattern)

```
var props = function(prop, queryprop) {
var queryprop = new RegExp(/john|c/);
if ( queryprop.test(prop) ) {
  console.log(prop);
};
return !prop
};

x = {
"a": {
    "name": "john",
    "age": "53",
    "more": "foo"
},
"b": {
    "test": "testing",
    "x": "c",
    "z": "b"
},
"c": {
    "foo": "testing",
    "bar": "2",
    "more": "lol"
}
};

$.each(x, function(index, value, _props) { 
  var _props = ["a", "b"];
  if (index === "a") { var name  = value.name; props(name); }; 
  if (index === "b") { var x = value.x; props(x); }; 
  return _props[index] != index;
});
```